# A few identities on differential forms

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

I just started studying differentiable manifolds, and I've encountered a few allegedly simple questions that aren't really simple to me.

If possible, I'd be very happy to see full proofs (without leaving logical gaps left out for adept readers, since I'm just getting used to these formalisms) of following identities:

1. $L_X (\omega \wedge \eta) = (L_X \omega ) \wedge \eta + (-1)^p \omega \wedge L_X \eta $ where $\omega$ is a p-form.
2. $L_X \omega = di_X \omega + i_Xd \omega$ where $d$ is exterior derivative and $i_X$ is interior derivative.
3. $ (L_{Y_0}\omega)(Y_1 \cdots Y_p) = L_{Y_0} (\omega(Y_1 \cdots Y_p )) - \sum_{k=1}^p \omega(Y_1  \cdots Y_{k-1} (L_{Y_0}Y_k) , \cdots Y_p)$
4. $d\omega (Y_0 \cdots Y_p) = \sum_{i=0}^p (-1)^i Y_i (\omega(Y_0 \cdots \hat Y_i \cdots Y_p)) + \sum_{i<j} (-1)^{i+j} \omega([Y_i,Y_j], Y_0 , \cdots \hat Y_i , \cdots \hat Y_j \cdots Y_p)$ where $\hat\cdot$ represents omission of that symbol.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Have you checked Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds"? Whatever he proves he does it very thoroughly.

Comment: These are standard results that are proved in standard books on manifolds. Your second one is misstated.

Comment: @BrunoStonek thank you, I checked the book and the book has rather comprehensive explanations.

TedShifrin yep, but I needed *full* explanations which aren't present in some books that I've read so far.